# Trying to reduce repetition of javascript using a variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, repeat

I am trying to reduce the repetition in my code but not having any luck. I reduced the code down to its simplest functionality to try and get it to work.

The idea is to take the last two letters of an id name, as those letters are the same as a previously declared variable and use it to refer to the old variable.

I used the **alert** to test whether I was getting the right output and the alert window pops up saying "E1". So I am not really sure why it wont work when I try and use it.

```
E1 = new Audio('audio/E1.ogg');

$('#noteE1').click(function() {
    var fileName = this.id.slice(4);
    //alert(fileName); used to test output
    fileName.play();
    $('#note' + fileName).addClass('active');
});
```

The code block works when I use the original variable **E1** instead of **fileName**. I want to use **fileName** because I am hoping to have this function work for multiple elements on click, instead of having it repeated for each element.

How can I make this work? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fileName` is still a **string**. JavaScript does not know that you want to use the variable with the same name. You are calling the `play()` method on a string, which of course does not exist (hence you get an error).

**Suggestion:**

Store your objects in a table:

```
var files = {
    E1: new Audio('audio/E1.ogg')
};

$('#noteE1').click(function() {
    var fileName = this.id.slice(4);
    //alert(fileName); used to test output
    files[fileName].play();
    $('#note' + fileName).addClass('active');
});
```

---

**Another suggestion:**

Instead of using the ID to hold information about the file, consider using [*HTML5 `data` attributes*](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/):

```
<div id="#note" data-filename="E1">Something</div>
```

Then you can get the name with:

```
var filename = $('#note').data('filename');
```

This makes your code more flexible. You are not dependent on giving the elements an ID in a specific format.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work. The file would not play.

Comment: +1, though I don't agree about the `id` thing. The ID has to be unique anyway, no particular reason not to use it to index into `files` and adding the `data-` attribute just adds to the size of the markup.

Comment: @tw16: *"The file would not play."* I just fixed a minor syntax error in Felix's code (there shouldn't be a `;` at the end of the `E1: ...` line). Try the update. Other than the syntax error, the recommendation is bang-on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the corrected syntax it works as expected.